# Transação XA não commita alterações em procedures (intermitente)

Tags: java, glassfish, pl-sql, ejb, transações

Eu tenho um EJB Stateles que monitora arquivos que caem em uma pasta. Quando um arquivo chega o mesmo é tratado, um evento de recebimento é registrado em um banco de dados central e o arquivo é inserido em um banco de dados de destino:

```
@Override
@Asynchronous
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void fileReceived(@Observes FileReceivedEvent fileReceivedEvent)
```

Esse processo envolve um banco de dados central, bem como um datasource / schema de destino que são obtidos em runtime (lookup JNDI):

```
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
                      res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" name="DBCentral">
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:1521/dbcentral">
     <property name="password" value="****"></property>
     <property name="user" value="DB_CENTRAL"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="DBCentral" jndi-name="jdbc/dbcentral"></jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
                      res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" name="DBDestino1">
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ip:1521/dbdestino">
     <property name="password" value=""*****"></property>
     <property name="user" value="DB_DESTINO1"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="DBDestino1" jndi-name="jdbc/dbdestino1"></jdbc-resource>
<!-- Destino 2, Destino 3, etc -->
```

O evento de recebimento de arquivos faz vários inserts e updates, bem como chamadas para stored procedures que também manipulam o banco:

```
final String procedureCall = "{call MEU_PACOTE.MEU_PROCEDURE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";
```

Habilitei os logs e todos os SQLs são gerados corretamente. Nenhuma exceção é disparada na camada EJB. Todos os comandos SQL, quando executados na mão, funcionam e geram entradas no banco.

O problema acontece nas chamadas de procedures. Volta e meia as alterações feitas pelas procedures não são persistidas no banco quando invocadas através do Java. Também recebemos exceções como `fetch out of sequence` do lado do PL/SQL.

Encontrei posts como [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606831/ora-01002-fetch-out-of-sequence-while-using-transactional) no SOen, porém não temos commits nem cursores for update no código (e, novamente, as exceções não estão sendo propagadas para o Java).

Se utilizar um DataSource não XA as procedures fazem o commit normalmente, porém nesse caso realmente precisamos de transações distribuídas para garantir a integridade da solução.

Conseguimos "eliminar" o problema tornando as transações autônomas do lado do PL/SQL:

```
PROCEDURE MEU_PROCEDURE(p_um       IN OUT VARCHAR2
                        , p_dois       IN NUMBER
                        , p_tres       IN OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
```

Porém essa não é uma solução ideal (o Java deveria controlar a transação e fazer rollback de todo o conjunto de operações em caso de erro).

Gostaria de saber se alguém já enfrentou um problema similar e como conseguiu resolver.

- Eu preciso fazer algo além de configurar DataSources XA e anotar meus EJBs para que o container faça o controle de transações distribuídas?
- O fato de estar fazendo lookup manual de DataSources (com `InitialContext`) pode estar influenciando?
- Existem alguns fluxos de exceção dentro do PL/SQL (`Exception When Others Then`). Nenhuma dessas exceções são disparadas de volta para o Java. Essas exceções que estão sendo tratadas dentro do PL/SQL podem estar impedindo o commit quando utilizamos transações distribuídas? Se sim, como faço para resolver o problema?

Comment: Existe algum comando `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ou qualquer DDL para alteração dinâmica do banco de dados dentro da procedure? Esse tipo de comando possui um `COMMIT` implícito por natureza e as transações autônomas são geralmente recomendadas para evitar problemas nesses casos.

Comment: Uma causa pouco provável, mas possível, é uma falha na implementação que coordena a transação distribuída. Pode ser lido na [documentação da Oracle sobre transações distribuídas em JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/xadistra.htm#JJDBC28854) que a ausência de um parâmetro `TMNOMIGRATE` em certos cenários pode causar o erro `fetch out of sequence`.

Comment: Oi utluiz, não há `EXECUTE IMEDIATE` e / ou SQL dinâmico. A sugestão do `TMNOMIGRATE` é muito boa, vou tentar.

Comment: Só para dar um *update*. Fiz o que pude para navegar no código do driver de JDBC com o IntelliJ 14 (o novo descompilador embutido é bem bacana) porém ainda não consegui isolar fluxos com *bug*. Dito isso, descobri que não preciso ter os dois `DataSources` configurados como XA (o GlassFish implementa *Last Agent Optimization*). Por enquanto estamos deixando o lado destino como não-XA. Isso "resolveu" os problemas.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria conseguir isolar este caso de intermitência. O ambiente é complexo e para dar uma resposta concreta precisamos saber se pelo menos no cenário feliz a transação ocorre com sucesso (commit). Depois disso, é preciso que você faça algum teste para saber se estamos conseguindo fazer o rollback no caso de exceções. É melhor que você isole os recursos: primeiro você tem que garantir um caso muito simples mas que funcione, ou seja, uma determinada classe de exceção lançada no java deveria causar o rollback. E depois vá avançando. Lembre-se que nem todas exceções no java causaria um rollback. Ou seja, systemException faz rollback, application exception não fazem rollback a não ser que você invoque o método setRollBackOnly(). (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html#bnciv)